# Is good practice to keep the ObjectId in a subdocument in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: schema, mongoose, document

I have defined in my model "File.js" this:

```
var FileSchema = new Schema({
     _id       : ObjectId
    name       : String
});
```

And in "Folder.js":

```
var FileSchema_Folder = new Schema({
     _id       : ObjectId // <--- is good practice to keep this id here?
    name       : String
});

var FolderSchema = new Schema({
     _id       : ObjectId
    files      : [FileSchema_Folder] // <--- UPDATE: replaced FileSchema for FileSchema_Folder
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every document already has an `_id` of type `ObjectId` by default, so it's not good practice to just repeat that in every schema.

Comment: sorry, my question was wrong, please check the update. thanks for you answer (:

Comment: My answer doesn't change. Putting `_id` in every schema is wrong.

Comment: But I think by default mongodb doesn't put an _id in the sub documents.. then how do I indentify them later without and _id?

Comment: Oh, I see; so there's no "Files" collection? In that case, it'll be useful to keep the ID only if you plan on using it somehow. That will be pretty hard since you won't be able to search through a collection for a given ID, instead you'll have to search through all folders for ones that contain a file with a given ID. Tricky...